# Restrict users to access pages simultaneously

Tags: php, mysql

how to restrict users to access pages simultaneously ?

example ,
user1 now access page1.php,
user2 want to access page1.php with link/button to access that page , but because user1 now was in page1 so user2 cannot access page1.php (and get redirect to previous page)

thanks in advance

Comment: Your server knows who has asked to view the page, and when, so it can keep track and grant unique access if that makes sense for your application. But you need to decide what to do if user1 loads the page and then leaves town...

Comment: i have no idea method to do that , how about if i make some user click link/button or load page1.php i updated database last_time_this_page_visited to NOW() , and then when another user click link/button to access page1.php he cannot access that page before interval 5 minutes , that is good method or not ?

Comment: If you don't mind locking pages for 5 min, it's a great method. I've no idea whether you _should_ mind: It depends on what your site is supposed to do. If you describe what this is for, you might get more useful advice.

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved in several ways, but first you need to define some constrains and definitions of how you want this to work. A page request through HTTP is performed quite quickly, and thus you cannot block one user viewing the page as another user viewing the page. What you can do however, is as user2874871, suggests and make a system where you log the access to the page, and then check the timestamp and if this is within the time you have defined as a watching session users are blocked. You do not need a SQL server to achieve this however, can do this using a file in the server filesystem. You can also see whether your web-server has functionality for blocking resources for a certain amount of time.